# Listener for actions in Android wear Notification

Tags: android, notifications, listener

In Android wear Application, how to listen for the actions in Notification. In my case, I have Approve button and deny button in Notification. How to listen for the action if it got tapped.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sf)
        .setContentTitle("John David")
        .setContentText("Quote approval")
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.prof))
        .addAction(R.drawable.generic_confirmation_00170,
                getString(R.string.agree), mapPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_full_cancel,
                getString(R.string.disagree), mapPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer this sample code of [http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html](http://developer.android.com/samples/Timer/Wearable/src/com.example.android.timer/SetTimerActivity.html)
and check the method buildNotification